# Putting html <a> into mysql table text field - url injection?

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

This is an awkward question but I am helping edit a site and there are some text fields in the MySQL table that I wanted to edit. One of the edits I wanted to do was add a hyperlink.

So I went ahead and put in `<a href = " etc. etc." </a>`. When I save it and view the website, the website injects the site's URL before my link breaking the link.

e.g. I am working `www.example.com` trying to insert a hyperlink to `www.google.ca`

It will output as `www.example.com/www.google.ca` instead of `www.google.ca`

I am pretty new to PHP/MySQL so I'm not sure if this is common or what is causing this. I tried looking at the file itself and the css to see if there was something causing this. I am not sure if this is even a normal thing or if there is a workaround it that I'm unaware of.

If anybody has ideas on where I should look (if they suspect it's the site that's injecting it), please let me know.

Comment: will you show us some code that you tried?

Comment: That's completely up to the custom code running your site, there is nothing remotely standard that does it. Try using `http://`, maybe whatever function is injecting the host is smart enough not to do so for fully qualified URLs.

Comment: i am directly editing in the myphpmyadmin. so i will write in
"BLAH BLAH BLAH <a href="www.google.ca">google</a>"

Comment: meagar is correct: If your link is outputted relative to your domain it means the browser thinks it is. At the very least put // in front of it to make it absolute or the specify protocol as well (http://)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above already:

```
<a href="www.google.ca">Google</a>
```

is a relative url and will output as http://yoursite.tld/www.google.ca

```
<a href="http://www.google.ca">Google</a>
```

will output as a correct link.

Comment: The protocol in itself (http and the ':') are optional for links within a page. If you just do //www.google.ca it will also work and it will use whatever protocol your page is loaded in the url-bar. :)

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the question. Thanks.